# Shiro 1.2.2: How to catch permissions of role

Tags: java, security, shiro

I want to know if any method exists that returns a boolean if a role has a particular permission, like this:

```
boolean roleHasPermission(String role, String permission);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem calling this function "AuthorizingRealm.clearCachedAuthorizationInfo" and then changing the roles query.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is something that is specific to your application logic. Shiro sees Roles and Permissions as two different entities. There is no ownership relationship, so there is no such method. Moreover, why would you check if a Role has a Permission? The way I see it, if the subject has that permission, then he must have that role, so just check the permission.

Comment: The user will select what is your current role after login, then, the menu will be diferent.